# When does NSURLConnection's initWithRequest return nil

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, null

Does anyone know in which situations initializing a `NSURLConnection` returns nil instead of the created connection. The documentation says it's possible but fails to specify when this happens.

The method/message in question:

`[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];`

-

According to the `NSURLConnection` Class Reference:

> Return Value: The URL connection for the URL request. Returns nil if a connection can't be initialized.

The URL Loading System Programming Guide says the following:

> If NSURLConnection can’t create a connection for the request, initWithRequest:delegate: returns nil.

-

While it's possible that this method returns nil, I'm unable to come up with a scenario which triggers this. I've tried the following scenarios:

- `URLRequest` with an empty url: `connection:didFailWithError:` delegate method is called with "unsupported URL" as error.
- `URLRequest` with invalid url: `connection:didFailWithError:` delegate method is called with "bad URL" as error.
- `URLRequest` with nonexistent url: `connection:didFailWithError:` delegate method is called with "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." as error.
- Valid request but no internet: `connection:didFailWithError:` delegate method is called with "The Internet connection appears to be offline." as error.
- nil request: causes a crash.

The `initWithRequest` method returned a valid `NSURLConnection` in each scenario (besides the last one) and called the `connection:didFailWithError:` with an appropriate error.

Has anybody been able to figure out which scenario does cause nil to be returned?

Comment: Why do you want to know? If it never happens, it's not a problem, right? :-)

Comment: It has happened actually and I'm trying to figure out what caused it. An Italian tester reported it... #hint

Comment: Any update on this? Still no satisfying answer ;(

Comment: On ios7/8 nil request does not cause a crash and init returns nil

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can also be used when it fails to *load*, not just *initialize*. (The *alloc* is done separately - that's where low mem would probably bite you) So (I'm guessing) it could fail because you did not have a network available (3G/Wifi) or it simply failed to connect to the server. In any event, use:

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

To get the actual failure.

You may be able to simulate this with an absence of a network - or even giving it a bad URL.

Comment: I have tested all scenarios you've mentioned, like I've mentioned in the question. No network connection/bad URL indeed call connection:didFailWithError. But that's not the question, I want to know when initializing fails. Guess I'll have to try to simulate a low memory situation.

Comment: If it returns nil, there will be no delegate callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is "Never". Seems only way for NSURLConnection to return nil is failing at [super init]. ([super init] returning nil) But as super class of NSURLConnection is NSObject and NSObjects init just returns self (never nil)

PS: That's for IOS SDK 4.0, on emulator, can be different on device.

Comment: This is consistent with it being an "init*" method - it's conforming to the general rule for `init` in NSObject subclasses: "Subclass implementations of this method should initialize and return the new object. If it can’t be initialized, they should release the object and return nil."

Comment: No, I've had it return nil before.

Answer (score 0):

I would try all of the above except do it during low memory conditions. IE, I think it will happen when an internal malloc fails.

Comment: Any tips on how to simulate/test this? Is there a smarter way than just allocating a lot of memory?

Answer (score 0):

I thing this is caused if the request u specified has wrong or not all essential values

Comment: Re-read the question, I have tested those scenarios as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection returns nil if it is not created inside a runLoop.