# iOS, check if an http or https server is listening in a specific port

Tags: ios

I need to find if a web server (sometimes in http, sometimes in https) is listening. I would prefer to do it synchronously and have a small timeout, e.g. 2-3 seconds.

What is the proper way to do it? I need to be backwards compatible with iOS 5.

UPDATE: I need to do it without external libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since OP cannot use external libs, implement the **`NSURLConnectionDelegate`** and use:

```
- (void)testUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                          timeoutInterval:3.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

    NSLog(@"GOT STATUS CODE: %d", responseStatusCode);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Done!");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I cannot add external code at this time

Comment: Updated the answer to suit.

Comment: Is this working? I don't think `-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:]` will return nil here. You would need to check the delegate methods for error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978020/when-does-nsurlconnections-initwithrequest-return-nil for more details.

Comment: @TRedman this code does not work. I tested with a false URL and the if statement was executed (CONNECTED). Why?

Comment: Sorry you need to implement the delegate protocols to handle the request. Answer updated.